# Error when creating Azure AD application on Graph API beta endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm posting the following payload to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications` endpoint:

```
{
  "displayName": "23e724af-2544-4764-ab56-520710fda746",
  "homepage": "https://23e724af-2544-4764-ab56-520710fda746",
  "identifierUris": [ "urn:23e724af-2544-4764-ab56-520710fda746" ],
  "replyUrls": [ "https://23e724af-2544-4764-ab56-520710fda746" ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [],
  "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg"
}
```

This fails with an HTTP 400 response with the following response body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "A value without a type name was found and no expected \
                type is available. When the model is specified, each value \
                in the payload must have a type which can be either specified \
                in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly \
                inferred from the parent value.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3de11d38-b10a-4711-baa5-0daee8af1b22",
      "date": "2019-03-04T07:20:37"
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

The service principal I'm making this call with has the `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, in the request body, you need to supply a JSON representation of [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta) object. See : [Request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta#request-body). The `homepage` and `replyUrls` are not its [properties](http://Properties), remove them, then it will work.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I managed to call the new endpoint with an old application object. Thanks for pointing this out!